# The current user folder will be changed on Windows Vista and 7

Tags: windows, winapi, uac

I have a application need to run under Administrator right, If I run it with Guest user account, after click the UAC dialog, using Windows API to get the current user folder in AP will be changed to Administrator folder, not Guest folder. How to solve it?

Comment: Not a programming question.  Check superuser.com

Comment: This actually does sound like a programming question- It sounds to me like Yigang Wants to programatically control the location where the location, which would require finding the uid that clicked "ok"on the UAC...

Comment: Yigang, This kind of thing can generally be answered with a search on MSDN.  You probably need to get your parent process's active user (start by searching msdn.com for GetCurrentProcessID). However, this may be easier if you include the code that triggers the UAC - are you calling CreateProcessAsUser, or executing from the command line, or triggering the UAC in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the current user folder before triggering the UAC dialog, store it somewhere and pass it to the code that runs after the UAC.

If this does not work for you, please explain why and post some code.

Comment: Depending upon the program, and how & where the data is stored, this could present a security risk.  If anyone can start the application (of course requiring another UAC dialog), then they could have it execute against any folder they want with admin privs.